# Getting SSRS Matrix Row Total for a Particular Column Value

Tags: reporting-services

In Microsoft Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 **Matrix**, I'd like to add a column that shows the percentage of one data item divided by the total count of that row's data items.

*Total*'s expression is `=Sum(Fields!Count.Value)`. How would I access the row's sum of Success from *Success Percent* so that I can do something like `=SUM(Fields!Count.Value WHERE Fields!Name.Value = "Success")/SUM(Total)`?

```
Adv.Name    Success         Failed  Total       Success Percent
A           2               8       10          20%
B           10              0       10          100%
C           8               2       10          80%
            ----------------------
            Data Items
                                    -----------
                                    Column Grp Total
```

[image: Report in Design Mode]

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah! This is rather easy! Aparently, the experession inside SUM is executed once per data item, allowing me to use a standard Iif statement to do the necessary filtering.

```
=SUM(Iif(Fields!Status.Value = "Success", Fields!Count.Value, 0))/SUM(Fields!Count.Value)
```