# SSRS - Row Total for Particular Column Value in matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

In SSRS,I'd like to add a column that shows the total count of all **Late, Annual Leave & Sick Leave** data for each individual row.

Currently, I'm just working on Late column & getting error on report like this.
[image]

by using following setting.. 
[image]

[this stack-overflow Solution isn't working as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203597/getting-ssrs-matrix-row-total-for-a-particular-column-value)

ThankYou...

Comment: Check if your dataset returns null values.

Comment: there is no null value in dataset, i replace null with 0

Comment: Use `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Activity.Value="Late",Fields!Count.Value,0),"EnrollId")` I am unsure about it but give it a try.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Same Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue related to `Count` field. It is possible that for some reason it is returning strings, hence `SUM` function cannot sum its values.

Try:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Activity.Value="Late",CINT(Fields!Count.Value),0),‌​"EnrollId")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: ThankYou @alejandrozuleta,
Thats what I'm Looking For, Works Perfectly.